# Missing toolbar in gvim 7.3

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, gvim

I recently compiled gVim 7.3.592 using gcc 4.7.1 from the MinGW distro available through [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net). It was built with Python 2/3 and Ruby language interfaces (or more specifically, I had set the PYTHON, PYTHON3, and RUBY definitions in the makefile for MinGW).

Here's [my gvimrc](http://pastebin.com/cqEPiSsX). I have a vimrc file that looks exactly similar.

For some reason, though, it looks like this:

[image]

How do I bring back the toolbar that was present in previous versions?

**UPDATE**: The issue occurs when I move the generated `gvim.exe` file out of the `src` directory into *any* other one. Bringing it back restores the toolbar icons and the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `:e $MYVIMRC` and then add the following and restart GVim, you should get things back to normal.

`set guioptions+=m "adds menu bar`

`set guioptions+=T "adds toolbar`

`set guioptions+=r "always present scrollbar`

You can also [refer to the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#guioptions) for a big list of options.

---

I decided I would try and go further and actually compile this myself. Downloaded the aforementioned `Ming` clone, and then cloned the [vim repository](https://code.google.com/p/vim/). I compiled it with no plugins initially, and then compiled it with all combinations of plugins (Ruby, LUA, Python, and Perl thrown in for good measure).

I haven't gotten the glitch you've gotten so far, and through the chat you've told me that your compilation on another machine works as well. From that, it's definitely something quirky in your build environment.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. According to the manual, these options are already enabled by default. I don't understand why this would not work "out of the box," so to speak - I've compiled gVim the same way before, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you got your vim version from? I want to give a shot at compilation but I can't seem to find it via vim/devel

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I got the source from https://code.google.com/p/vim/ (just cloned the repo).

Comment: I just compiled 592 without perl, ruby, python (I'm going to recompile with each of these options in a sec). It displays the correct things for me. Did you try compiling multiple times, or was this the first runthrough?

Comment: Trying it now...

Comment: Well, just compiled with all 3 and still got the menu. What was the command you used to compile? In your `Make_ming.mak` file, what options are you using (or are you specifying them on the command line?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4077/discussion-between-isxek-and-qweet)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on windows for gvim(8.0). In my case the problem was not that the guioptions were set incorrectly. It turned out that I managed to delete some of the needed files for menus/etc from the vim directory.

So, looking at your problem, it seems that the executable could not find the files needed to create the menus and buttons. My solution was to re-extract the vim runtime archive into the vim directory which replaced the missing files. In your case you could either extract the runtime files to whichever directory vim is running from or copy the files and subdirectories from the location where the menus are working.

ps. for gvim80 the runtime archive is vim80-069rt.zip.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Perhaps I could have worded my answer/comment differently but the underlying issue that I had and the original question had were the same.  Namely, vim could not find the configuration files for rendering the menus and buttons.  I added the extra info in hoping it might be more generally useful.

Comment: The empty icon bar in the pic that was posted as part of the question proves that **this answer is indeed the right answer**. The issue does not pertain to missing options, but to missing files.

Answer (score 0):

`:h guioptions` for more information. Vim has a great documentation :)

If you want a quick answer:

```
if has("gui_running")
  set guioptions-=m     "remove menu bar
  set guioptions-=T     "remove tool bar
  set guioptions-=r     "remove left scroll
  set guioptions-=l     "remove right scroll
endif
```

Comment: This is more of an rtfm comment than an answer. While it is OK to suggest that the OP read the documentation, if you are going to answer, please provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the location where `gvim.exe` was moved into, create a new directory named `vim73`. At minimum, the following files and folders should be inside `vim73`:

- `menu.vim`
- the `autoload` directory
- the `colors` directory

I did not check further which particular files within either the `autoload` and the `colors` directories were actually needed, but fulfilling this requirement solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was driving me nuts.  Finally I figured out that I didn't have a VIMRUNTIME environment variable set.

Once I set that to point to the directory where vim was installed, it could then see menu.vim and all was right with the world.  So I would make sure to check that.